# Test database to test performance tuning techniques in Oracle

Tags: oracle, testing, performance, dataset

I want to test some performance tuning techniques on a realistic database with many database tables and a lot of data. I would like to do this in Oracle 11g Release 1 and would like to know how best to go about this or if there is a website I could get realistic datasets/database from.

Many thanks for your audience.

Cheers,
Tunde

Comment: How many is many and how much is a lot?

Comment: Hmmm,Many is not that much, say 10-15 database tables each with minimum of like a million rows of data. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you can choose something from [this](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Database+Benchmarking).

Answer (score 1):

Good timing. There was a [blog entry today](http://husnusensoy.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/create-your-own-oracle-tpc-h-playground-on-linux/) on generating the data for the TPC-H benchmark.

Comment: Thanks Gary but I would want to do this test on a Windows machine, does TPC-H have a windows version? Cheers